# Library Class not found in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am migrating a working production L3 site to use L4. When a controller calls a library class (`app/libraries/adminthing.php`), I get the error `Error: Class 'adminthing' not found in /var/www/l4/app/controllers/AdminController.php line 15`

**start/global.php**

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/libraries',

));
```

I have also done `composer dumpautoload` after adding the library class. What else did I miss out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can autoload folders from composer.json. If you have some custom classes in a folder under /app you can add the folder to composer.json, and after this the classes are auto loaded.

```
"autoload": {
  "classmap": [
    "app/commands",
    "app/controllers",
    "app/models",
    "app/database/migrations",
    "app/database/seeds",
    "app/tests/TestCase.php",
    "app/customlib" <-- add this
  ]
},
```

Then composer dump-autoload, and you can use the classes!

Comment: Is it possible to have the same behavior as in L3? By using Laravel's Class Autoloader to track classes in /app/libraries folder instead of relying on composer's

Comment: I guess you could, but because laravel 4 is heavily composer based, i would recommend loading everything with composer. The

Comment: Yup your suggestion works! The strange thing is that `ClassLoader::addDirectories()` does not work

Comment: Another solution could be to create package(s) for laravel using the workbench, this way you could use your packages in other projects simply by including them in your app/app/providers array. And maybe even share them with fellow laravelians :)